# Running suspicious X programs in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, security, x-windows, x-server

What the most harmful thing can malware program started as separate limited user account do if it has access to the X server?

Network and filesystem things are already considered by chroot and netfilter.

It obviously can lock the screen and I will need to switch to other vt and kill it manually.
Can it for example disrupt other GUI programs on the same X server (access a root terminal in nearby window)?

I know that it is safer to run it in separate X server, for example, in Xtightvnc or even some virtual machine, but how dangerous is to just run it like other programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already gone to the trouble of setting up a separate X server, have you considered running the program inside a nested X-server like Xnest.  Then, you would completely isolate the malicious program in its own X envrionment.  Or if you want to be absoutely safe, you might even consider something VirtualBox for a whole other VM.

Answer (score 0):

Once a program has access to the X server it can virtually do everything you can do with a mouse and a keyboard. This will not be limited to this application's window should it have one, but could affect other running applications.

There are tons of applications to help people with accessibility-related problems assisting them to use the keyboard or the mouse to control their X sessions. Why should malware not do that and just pretend to be you?

Comment: Example: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/ It's not a virus, it's a GUI scripting engine that *you* can use to script arbitrary actions, like clicking on GUI buttons and typing in text boxes and stuff. I'm just providing it as an example of what capabilities a malicious program would have access to.

Answer (score 0):

[Install Zephyr](http://labs.o-hand.com/xephyr/) and then :

```
Zephyr -ac -screen 800x600 -br -reset -terminate :2 &
```

to run a [nested/isolated x session](http://wahjava.wordpress.com/2007/08/01/wanna-run-a-nested-x-server/).

Jim